# Pause a CCMoveBy Cocos2d 2.0 ios

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

im developing a game where i have time to finish the level, during wich i have a filling bar animation, on that particular animation im using CCMoveBy:

```
  self.animatedBar = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:time position: ccp(12, -20)];
  CCNode* animatedContainer = [self getChildByTag:1];
  [animatedContainer runAction:self.animatedBar];
```

is there any way to say something like [animatedBar pause] and [animatedBar resume] ?
Or the best bet is to put this into my game loop and pause it there? ( im doing a return if the BOOL paused is set to true ).
I will have more animations attached to this on the future ( not game core related, but just to make it more "shinny" ) so i want to avoid using:

```
  [animatedContainer pauseSchedulerAndActions];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pause/resume method for action in cocos2d, so the first way - you can implement your own CCAction subclass, that will allow this, or just stop current action and recreate it instead of unpause.